# Communication between microservices pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to use microservices architecture for my next project based on ASP.NET core.

I could exchange between the services via REST but it is really heavy to maintain.

Is there an other way for communication between microservices, for example over event bus like vertx.

I could use rabbitmq, but do not know, if it is a good option.

Comment: This is pretty broad and opinion based, so not very suitable for stackoverflow, so I'll just post it as comment: You have two choices basically, go with all Microsoft and use Service Fabric and reliable services or use a third party library like Microphone (github.com/rogeralsing/Microphone) together with a distributed key/value store (i.e. etcd, consol, redis etc)

Comment: Do service fabric support mac os x?

Comment: As far as I know, nope. As of now you also need the full .NET Framework, but you didn't specify this in your initial question as ASP.NET Core runs on both .NET Core and full .NET Framework. But it runs either on-premises or on Azure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Rabbit MQ is going to work OK, especially if you have many consumers i.e. need load balancing, and/or if you need messages to be persistent, and also if conceptually, your micro-services are OK processing messages.

Otherwise, since you’re considering REST, I’d recommend WCF instead.

Just ignore Microsoft’s examples, those are too complex. You need to make an assembly containing protocols (in WCF terminology, service contracts) + messages they send/receive (in WCF terminology, data contracts) that’ll be shared between your services. Having a shared assembly will allow you to get rid of that enterprise-style XML configuration nonsense. This will also make maintenance simpler than REST, because the compiler is going to verify the correctness of your network calls: you forget to update one service after changing a protocol, and the service will stop compiling.

[Here’s my demo](https://github.com/Const-me/EsentSerialize/tree/master/Demos/ClientServer) which uses WCF to implement zero-configuration client-server communications in C#.
It’s currently set up to use named pipe binding i.e. will only work locally. But it’s easy to switch from `NetNamedPipeBinding` to `NetTcpBinding` which will do networking just fine.

P.S. If you’ll pick WCF, don’t forget the abstraction can and will leak. Any network call may fail with any network-related exception. Also you’ll need to reconnect sometimes (if you don’t want to, and your don’t have too many messages per second, you can use a connection-less protocol like `NetHttpBinding` but those are much less performant).

Comment: what about grpc for .net?

Comment: Probably good for heterogeneous environments. However, when you have .NET on both ends of the socket, protobuff is more fragile and more expensive to maintain. More points of failure: extra language for the protocol (in WCF you directly write C# interfaces and classes), extra build step makes it harder to change the protocol (WCF uses reflection in runtime).

Comment: Manually written C# classes are easier to deal with, you can include some logic in your messages like constructors/converters/formatters, with protobuff you’re limited to plain data structures. Finally, in my experience, .NET framework has less bugs and performs better than third-party libraries, especially third-party ports of cross-platform stuff.

Comment: @Soonts: To be noted here is that there is no WCF for .NET Core. Not sure if and how far it can be used with ASP.NET Core running against .NET Framework, but you're lucky you can plug it with the Owin configuration into the ASP.NET Core application

Comment: @Tseng technically you’re right, sadly. But practically, we have this: https://github.com/MhAllan/TcpServiceCore We can even use same data contract+binary XML serialization, as XmlDictionaryReader/Writer are available in DNC.